# C++ CGI - Internal Server Error - when is used string

Tags: c++, cgi

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        cout << "content-type: text/html" << endl << endl;
        cout << "<h1>CGI C++ example</h1>" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

after compilation (in Ubuntu, Apache2) and uploading in my website host, in /cgi-bin/ folder, it works normal
Bit if I add string after compilation (in Ubuntu, Apache2) and uploading in my website host, the result is  "Internal Server Error"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        cout << "content-type: text/html" << endl << endl;
        string alabala;
        cout << "<h1>CGI C++ example</h1>" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for comments

Comment: The second program is perfectly legal. Whatever the cause of your error it's got nothing to do with the code you have posted. Presumably the problem is something in the way you are using the host.

Comment: You should find more information in your web server's logs.

Comment: In previous version of the code I included 'string alabala = "Somethig";' and 'cout << alabala << endl;' - the same error.  After that I just simplified the code to find which line cause error and it is "string alabala;"

Comment: @RaUndreundre Assuming that you've done everything right, then the only possible cause I can think of is some kind of versioning issue in the C++ runtime library. Can't really help you with that, the *code* is fine.

Comment: @RaUndreundre Are you able to open a console window your host? That would be the way to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @john Thanks for the ideas. I'll try tomorrow and inform

Comment: I did not found console window in my host. I asked my hosting provider to compile this cpp file and it is running normal. They use g++ 4.8.5 and I use g++ 7.5.0. Maybe the problem is we are using different versions. Unfortunately I didn't have a success to install lower version of g++, no matter I spent several days for this.

Comment: I got success to install g++ 4.8.4 and now everything run normal

Answer (score 1):

I found some webhost company blocks non perl cgi script! Then I tried foo.pl is fine! but if i compile from pascal or c++ it fails! The only solution for me, so far is to use VPS with personalized apache conf for my purpose.